# Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :

Tags: r

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open file 'c:\Users\Administrator.vscode\extensions\reditorsupport.r-2.7.1\R\session\init.R': No such file or directory

what should i do？ help！！！

ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Comment: can you provide more detail?

Comment: *"No such file or directory"* means you should check if a) the file exists, b) in the current working directory.